# Spring MVC the right way call different methods by one link

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I tried create login page with spring security. I need realize some type of login. And URL for login must the same. For examle

I open main login page - `localhost:8080/login`

Then I input some information and press button "next"

I move to `localhost:8080/default/login`

On this page I have two type of login - by ip, by sms, by etc. And if I press button "by ip" I need see url - `localhost:8080/default/login`

but call in controller method `loginByIp();`

And if I press button "by sms" I need see url - `localhost:8080/default/login`

but call in controller method `loginBySms();`

I found solution

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/default/login", params = "sms", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView sms(@RequestParam String msisdn) {
//login by sms
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/default/login", params = "ip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ip(@RequestParam String msisdn) {
//login by ip
}
```

And in form on the page I create hidden param

```
<input class="form-control" name="type" value="ip" type="hidden"/>
```

or

```
<input class="form-control" name="type" value="sms" type="hidden"/>
```

And in each form I call

```
<form action="/default/login" method="post">
```

It work. But I thing it is bad practik or maybe exist  more easy or correct side.

Answer (score 0):

As you are referring to two different actions, in my opinion the best way would be to assign them different REST endpoints

- sms: `/default/login/by-sms`
- ip: `/default/login/by-ip`

And then the forms would look like:

```
<form action="/default/login/by-ip" method="post">...</form>
...
<form action="/default/login/by-sms" method="post">...</form>
```

And the handlers mapped cleanly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/default/login/by-sms", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginBySms(@RequestParam String msisdn) {
//login by sms
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/default/login/by-ip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginByIp(@RequestParam String msisdn) {
//login by ip
}
```

Thus it would be more easy to understand / maintain.

Otherwise your approach would work as well.

Comment: is the standard way. and natural right. but my task is to show the same link

Comment: @Matyas I agree, single responsability principle, different actions, differents endpoints

Comment: **"show the same link"** - what do you mean by that? The browser URL of the page may be the same, it's only the `action` of the form that would be different, which is not visible to the user. Moreover after a successful login, you may redirect to the same page in both cases.